# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property..." on Blockly

Tags: javascript, jquery, blockly

I am starting coding on Blockly but I have a problem when I try to create new blocks. The steps I made:

- Download the `Blockly` application [code](https://github.com/google/blockly).
- I put all the files in a folder named `Blockly`.
- I created a new html file in that folder to see if the toolbox worked fine.
- I created two new blocks with [Block Factory](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/blockfactory/index.html).
- I tried to add these new blocks to the toolbox with a new `customBlocks.js` file.

The problem comes when I try to make the fourth step because I have added two new blocks but it is only displayed on the toolbox the first one I have on the js, but never the second one, it does not matter the order of the blocks, just the second one never will be displayed correctly.

Here is my `html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="blockly_compressed.js"></script>
        <script src="blocks_compressed.js"></script>
        <script src="customBlocks.js"></script>
        <script src="msg/js/en.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a prove </h1>
        <div id = "blocklyMove" style = "height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
        <div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 480px; width: 600px;"></div>

        <xml id="toolbox" style="display: none">
          <block type="controls_if"></block>
          <block type="controls_repeat_ext"></block>
          <block type="logic_compare"></block>
          <block type="math_number"></block>
          <block type="math_arithmetic"></block>
          <block type="text"></block>
          <block type="text_print"></block>
          <block type="move_right"></block>
          <block type="blockObject"></block>
        </xml>

        <script>
          var workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv',
              {toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `customBlocks.js` file:

```
'use strict';

/* *********************** MOVES TO RIGHT *********************** */

Blockly.Blocks['move_right'] = {
  init: function() {
    this.appendValueInput("PIXELS")
        .setCheck("Number")
        .appendField("move to right");
    this.setInputsInline(true);
    this.setOutput(true, null);
    this.setColour(120);
    this.setTooltip('');
    this.setHelpUrl('http://www.example.com/');
  }
};

Blockly.JavaScript['move_right'] = function(block) {
  var value_pixels = Blockly.JavaScript.valueToCode(block, 'PIXELS', Blockly.JavaScript.ORDER_ATOMIC);
  // TODO: Assemble JavaScript into code variable.
  var code = "$(document).ready(function(){ " +
                "$(\"blocklyMove\").animate({ " + 
                    "right: " + value_pixels + "px" +
                "});" +
            "});";
  // TODO: Change ORDER_NONE to the correct strength.
  return [code, Blockly.JavaScript.ORDER_NONE];
};

/* *********************** BLOCK *********************** */

Blockly.Blocks['blockObject'] = {
  init: function() {
    this.appendValueInput("MOVEMENT")
        .setCheck(null)
        .appendField("Block");
    this.setColour(20);
    this.setTooltip('');
    this.setHelpUrl('http://www.example.com/');
  }
};

Blockly.JavaScript['blockObject'] = function(block) {
  var value_movement = Blockly.JavaScript.valueToCode(block, 'MOVEMENT', Blockly.JavaScript.ORDER_ATOMIC);
  // TODO: Assemble JavaScript into code variable.
  var code = '...;\n';
  return code;
};
```

I could see that it gives to me the following error on the console of `Google Chrome`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'move_right' of undefined

I am stuck here and I cannot figure out what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

**P.S: Do not focus on the logic of the blocks because I did not finish them yet, but I wanted to see that both blocks will be displayed correctly before finish the logic.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not care if you downvote me but please explain me why. I think a downvote without an explanation wont help any of us. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. On the `html` file I had to add the following `<script>` tag to make reference to another `js` file (javascript_compressed.js) in which `Blockly.JavaScript` it is defined:

```
<script src="javascript_compressed.js"></script>
```